# Is it possible to set an individual sound volume for each program on a Mac?

Tags: macos, applications, sound-volume

I would like to be able to lower the volume of certain software without lowering the overall volume, I know that we can do this very easily on a PC, but on my Macbook Pro (2012) (Catalina) I can't do it.

would there be a possibility to do this on Mac ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What specific Mac (iMac, Macbook, MBP, etc) and what OS version?  Also, what have you already tried?  If looking for 3rd-party apps, see [this post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for info you need to add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a way to do it for free with the app [Background Music](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic):

> - Automatically pause/unpause your music player when other audio sources are playing/stopped
> - Per-application volume control
> - Record system audio
> - No restart required to install

Answer (score 1):

This is not functionality built into macOS. Windows audio was miles behind Mac for many years, but they got this ability natively first. There are only two apps I know can do this, both by the same company, Rogue Amoeba.

The cheaper & simpler one is [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) - $35. There is a more complex/expensive one which can also record any sound source to disk as well, called [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) - $70.

SoundSource can do all you asked & more.